# Laravel Vapor queue-concurrency

Tags: laravel-vapor

Just checking what happens when we hit queue-concurrency limit.

For example if I had a cron that added 100 items to my queue.

```
queue-concurrency=25
```

Would aws throw out the extra 75?
Or does it just limit concurrency to 25 at once and still process them all?

I get regular concurrency limit is for ddos protection but for queues this could be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs them all and uses the concurrency limit.
Setting a low queue-concurrency can save you lambda time spinning up extra containers if you are ok with the jobs being queued up for a while. Nothing is thrown out as with the regular concurrency limit.